# how to strip a variable using logback after a delimiter

Tags: logstash, logback, spring-logback

I am utilizing Logback for some logging and my current `logback-spring.xml` file contains the following lines:

```
<property resource="git.properties"/>

...

<appender name="LOGSTASH" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashAccessTcpSocketAppender">
    <destination>localhost:5000</destination>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <customFields>{ "branch":"${git.branch}"</customFields>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Now in my output, I properly get the name of my git branch.  But my branches utilize the following naming convention <issue#>-description-more-details. So if I'm working on Issue #747 Fix logging, my branch name would be `747-fix-logging`.

What I would like to do is add additional output that simply outputs the Issue number.  so my log would look like the following:

```
[yyyy-mm-dd] INFO --- 747-fix-logging
[yyyy-mm-dd] INFO --- 747
```

I know it's stupid but I've learned just not to ask questions.  Any help would be great.